# Re-applying git commit

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I had a commit with a pull-request already merged in the development branch. Then after a weak someone made a mistake and merged the master branch back to the development and somehow, i don't know how, but my already merged commit is now gone from the development branch.

I can track down the commits to dev branch after my commit, and I could track down where it went wrong, but the PR for the commit which broke/erased my merged commit doesn't show my files as if it would be changed by that commit.

Long story short, some code got reverted to an old state by a commit and there are no signs of it, how can I re-apply a commit to the dev branch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to find the commit sha-1 value that you made the changes, and then cherry-pick this commit to your `development` branch:

```
git checkout development
git cherry-pick <commit you found>
```

Comment: Will this work if the development branch already has these commits in it's history?

Comment: Yes, it works even the commit exist in the same branch. But when you cherry-pick this commit, there may have some conflicts, you need to modify and save the conflict files, and use `git add .` and `git cherry-pick --continue` to finish it.

Comment: Does the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: @Jim-Y Please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem.